# Compare two tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

Compare services of two tables and showing only those services which are not assigned to user 1

Table 1: Services

```
id | Service 
--------------
1  | service 1
--------------
2  | service 2
--------------
3  | service 3
--------------
4  | service 4
--------------
5  | service 5
```

Table 2: Assigned Service

```
id | services | assign_to | date
--------------------------------------
1  | service 1| 1         | 20/12/2019
--------------------------------------
2  | service 2| 1         | 20/12/2019
--------------------------------------
3  | service 1| 2         | 20/12/2019
--------------------------------------
3  | service 3| 1         | 20/12/2019
--------------------------------------
3  | service 2| 2         | 20/12/2019
```

I tried RIGHT AND LEFT Join like

```
SELECT a.x, a.y
FROM table_a a LEFT JOIN table_b b
ON a.x = b.x AND a.y = b.y
WHERE b.x IS NULL;
```

Comment: What about services which are not assigned to any user?

Comment: These should also be displayed in the output @Nick

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your data, some services are assigned to user 1 and 2, do you want them in the output results? Can you perhaps include the expected output in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find services which are not assigned to user 1 (including those not assigned to any user) by using a `LEFT JOIN` on services which are assigned to user 1 and checking for a `NULL` result:

```
SELECT s.id, s.service
FROM services s
LEFT JOIN assignments a ON a.services = s.service AND a.assign_to = 1
WHERE a.id IS NULL
```

Output:

```
id  service     
4   service 4   
5   service 5
```

If you want all services that have been assigned to no user, or to a user other than 1 (even if they have also been assigned to 1), you can use this query:

```
SELECT s.id, s.service
FROM services s
LEFT JOIN assignments a ON a.services = s.service
GROUP BY s.id, s.service
HAVING SUM(a.assign_to != 1) > 0 
    OR SUM(a.assign_to) IS NULL
```

Output

```
id  service
1   service 1
2   service 2
4   service 4
5   service 5
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/56c6XBX3WqxGrfzxXeH5xC/0)

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions:

```sql
SELECT s.id, a.service
FROM services AS s 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM assigned_service AS a 
  WHERE a.assign_to = 1 -- your wanted user id
  AND a.services = s.service
)
```